# How to make an interactive objects using PhotonNetwork?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

On the stage, I create several objects using `PhotonNetwork.Instatiate ();`
On these objects there is a script that changes the `transform` of the object. In the same script, a random variable is selected from the list, depending on which the `transform` is changing.

Now the question. How do I make this object change its `transform` simultaneously and equally for all players?

I'm thinking of doing something like this: make a separate script that will select a random number -> in it, write something like this

```
if (view.isMaster) // ???????
for (int i = 0; ......) {
objectInList [i] .myFloatValue = randomValueInArray;
objectInList [i] .canToChange = true;
}
```

And in the script of a mutable object, write something like:

```
if (canToChange)
// change the position;
```

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more detail about what you're trying to accomplish. I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: @AdamB On the objects there is a script, which once every `5 seconds` (or any other time) moves the object to `x + 1`, `x + 2` or `x + 3` to the side. The figure is selected randomly every `5 seconds`. The problem is that in this case each player has an object moving in its own way, and I need that all players with the object with `viewID == 1` move the same, `with viewID == 2` moved the same and so on

Comment: I'm sorry but you're referring to things that aren't explained. Please update your question to answer the following: how are things currently set up? What's going wrong? And what have you tried to fix it. Remember, we aren't intimately familiar with your project like you are so you need to explain more background